# Ajax request not working in my php code

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am sending ajax request to a php page where i am checking my username and password. Here is may ajax code:

```
success: function(response)
            {
                if(response === "success"){             
                                                    $(location).attr('href','adminHome.php');
                                        }
                else
                    $("#message").html('<p class="error">ERROR: Invalid username and/or password.'+response+'</p>');
            }
```

In the php code i am connecting to database. and checking whether the username password exists.

Here is my php code

```
  $sql="SELECT * FROM mainadmin where username='$username' and password='$password'";
            $result = mysql_query($sql);
            $numrows = mysql_num_rows($result);
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
            {
                echo $row['username']." ".$row['password'];
            }
            if($numrows>0)
            {
                $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
                echo "success";                  
            }
```

The correct user and password is being returned from the database its not being redirected to adminHome.php page. What is the error here i am making? The code is always executing the else part of the success in ajax showing the warning message.

Comment: What's in the `response` variable when that `else` block is executed?

Comment: You are echoing the user name and password so response won't equal `success`. You probably don't need that while loop at all. Also are you sanitizing the username and password?

Comment: else block is executed with echo "failed"

Comment: Comment out the echo $row. Does it work then?

Comment: Hello chris85 i deleted those and tried but same thing happened. Usually i added those echo to test whether correct values are returned from database

Comment: Here is the output which comes from else part of success ERROR: Invalid usernameConnected to MySQL
success and/or password. Hello

Comment: look success is going to new line. Is it a problem? How to solve it?

Comment: Try `if(response.trim() === "success"){`, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim.

Comment: yea I am guessing that there are invisible line breaks or other characters in the response, trim is a good call.

Comment: where is that Connected to MySQL string coming from in your response?

Comment: trim is not working to. Even i tried with response.toString().trim(). Thats also not working

Comment: This is your full code? As noted above the `Connected to MySQL` shouldn't be present based on the above code..

Comment: Something is echoing 'Connected to MySQL' somewhere in your code, you need to remove that because that is what is causing the issue with your response message.

Comment: Oh now i got it. The database script was printing this line. Now fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```
  $sql="SELECT * FROM mainadmin where username='$username' and password='$password'";
  $result = mysql_query($sql);
  $numrows = mysql_num_rows($result);
  $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

  if($numrows>0)
  {
      $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
      echo "success";                  
  } else {
      echo 'error';
  }
```

I believe the issue is because you are echoing out the username and password and then success so when you check the value of $result it does not equal what you think it does.

I am truly hoping that you are also sanitizing the $username and $password variables and I would suggest you migrate to using PDO rather than mysql_ function as they are deprecated and will be removed from PHP in the very near future.  If you cannot or do not wish to use PDO then simply migrate to using mysqli_* functions or objects.  I highly suggest you go the route of PDO with bound parameters for your variables though.

Comment: Are you following the comments?